# Is there a randomize function that returns values of a chosen type?

Tags: java, random

Is there a way to use a randomize function with relation to a give data type, i.e.
if I request the type is `double` then I will get `double` values, and if the requested type is `float` I will get `float` values?

Is there such a randomize function?

Comment: There is no such built in method. You would have to write your own, or create a method on the type to provide a random number of the same type using generics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java 1.7:
Either you call `ThreadLocalRandom.current().next<DataType>()` by yourself, or you write a wrapper around this call:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

//...

public static int nextRandom(int maxValueExclusive)
{
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(maxValueExclusive);
}

public static long nextRandom(long maxValueExclusive)
{
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong(maxValueExclusive);
}

public static double nextRandom(double maxValueExclusive)
{
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(maxValueExclusive);
}

public static float nextRandom(float maxValueExclusive)
{
    if (maxValueExclusive <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must be positive: " + maxValueExclusive);
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextFloat()*maxValueExclusive;
}

public static boolean nextRandom(boolean unusedValue)
{
    return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBoolean();
}
```

---

java 1.6:

```
import java.util.Random;

//...

private static final Random random = new Random(); // be careful with multiple threads

public static int nextRandom(int maxValueExclusive)
{
    return random.nextInt(maxValueExclusive);
}

public static long nextRandom(long maxValueExclusive)
{
    //implementation from java 1.7 ThreadLocalRandom
    if (maxValueExclusive <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must be positive: " + maxValueExclusive);
    // Divide n by two until small enough for nextInt. On each
    // iteration (at most 31 of them but usually much less),
    // randomly choose both whether to include high bit in result
    // (offset) and whether to continue with the lower vs upper
    // half (which makes a difference only if odd).
    long offset = 0;
    while (maxValueExclusive >= Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        long half = maxValueExclusive >>> 1;
        long nextn = random.nextBoolean() ? half : maxValueExclusive - half;
        if (random.nextBoolean())
            offset += maxValueExclusive - nextn;
        maxValueExclusive = nextn;
    }
    return offset + random.nextInt((int) maxValueExclusive);
}

public static double nextRandom(double maxValueExclusive)
{
    if (maxValueExclusive <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must be positive: " + maxValueExclusive);
    return random.nextDouble()*maxValueExclusive;
}

public static float nextRandom(float maxValueExclusive)
{
    if (maxValueExclusive <= 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument must be positive: " + maxValueExclusive);
    return random.nextFloat()*maxValueExclusive;
}

public static boolean nextRandom(boolean unusedValue)
{
    return random.nextBoolean();
}
```

Comment: Thanks TB - but when I tried for instance to call to return ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble(maxValueExclusive); I got error :ThreadLocalRandom cannot be resolved there is some import that i should add here ?

Comment: @OlafBergin If you did not, you have to import it: import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom; You need Java7 as well, If you do not have Java7, I can provide a Java6 version.

Comment: Thanks TB but I have java6

Comment: @OlafBergin I have update my post with java6 version. It should work, but I did not tested it with a clean java6 environment. Comment if there are some problems.

Comment: Thanks TB this is working ,btw can you please explain what is this code line long half = maxValueExclusive >>> 1;  >>> ?

Comment: in addition what do you mean  "be careful with multiple threads",how ?

Comment: `>>>`this is a bit shift, an unsigned right shift, see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html If you do not know it, ignore it. This part of algorithm will just take care of the upper part of the long (to imagine: the long is composed by 2 integers)

Comment: `multiple threads`: From the java documentation: `Instances of java.util.Random are threadsafe. However, the concurrent use of the same java.util.Random instance across threads may encounter contention and consequent poor performance. Consider instead using ThreadLocalRandom in multithreaded designs.` I do not think that you have to care about it, it is just a hint for anyone reading this.